# How to delay one clock cycle in STM32?

Tags: assembly, clock, stm32, stm32ldiscovery

The question is as simple as the topic. How to delay exact one clock cycle in STM32?
If the controller runs at 168MHz, is one clock cycle equal to 1/168MHz, which is 5.95ns?

Comment: It seems like this might provide the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220928/processor-instruction-cycle-execution-time

Comment: I just read the thread, thanks! It seems that the processor is running based on a different structure..

Comment: What could I do if I need exact timing to communicate with hardwares, such as a very high speed ADC?

Answer (score 13):

You can try to use assembly in your C code.  Its quite easy with the asm() function.  I believe it would look like this:

```
asm("NOP");
```

This is just the assembly instruction for 'Don't do anything for this PC tick'.  Also you should make sure that your compiler does not optimize it out.